# Wrapping D3 functions inside objects doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I assign a d3.scale function to a variable I can pass in a number and it will scale that number correctly.

However, if I wrap that same function in an object it does not return the answer I expect.  Why?

```
var applyScale1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([0, 2])
    .rangePoints([0, 1024]);

console.log(typeof(applyScale1));     // "function"
console.log(applyScale1(1));          // 0
console.log(applyScale1(5000));       // 1024 *Correct*

// But wrapping that in an object doesn't work. Why?

var obj = {

  returnResult: function(n) {
    var fn = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain([0, 2])
      .rangePoints([0, 1024]);

    return fn(n);
  },

  returnFunction: function() {
    return d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain([0, 2])
      .rangePoints([0, 1024]);
  },

  withCall: function(n) {
    var fn = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain([0, 2])
      .rangePoints([0, 1024]);

    var nScaled = fn.call(n);
    return nScaled;
  },

  applySelf: function(n) {
    var self = this;
    var fn = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain([0, 2])
      .rangePoints([0, 1024]);

    var nScaled = fn.apply(self, [n]);
    return nScaled;
  },

  usingCall: function(n) {
    return d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain([0, 2])
      .rangePoints([0, 1024])
      .call(n);
  },
};

console.log(obj.returnResult(1));         // = 0
console.log(obj.returnResult(5000));      // = 0 * Wrong *

console.log(obj.returnFunction()(1));     // = 0
console.log(obj.returnFunction()(5000));  // = 0 * Wrong *

console.log(obj.withCall(1));             // = 0
console.log(obj.withCall(5000));          // = 0 * Wrong *

console.log(obj.applySelf(1));            // = 0
console.log(obj.applySelf(5000));         // = 0 * Wrong *

console.log(obj.usingCall(1));            // = 0
console.log(obj.usingCall(5000));         // = 0 * Wrong *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an ordinal scale, which is a scale with a discrete domain.  In your case, that discrete domain is the set {0, 2}.  I'm not sure how the behavior would be defined if you put in a number not in that set 1024, but I believe d3 leaves this undefined.

If you pass in 0 or 2, the results will be as expected.

One other issue is in this statement:

```
return d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain([0, 2])
  .rangePoints([0, 1024])
  .call(n);
```

The first argument to call is the 'thisArg': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

That block should read:

```
return d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain([0, 2])
  .rangePoints([0, 1024])
  .call(null, n);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cesutherland/5gY6Z/2/

Comment: The code found in the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cesutherland/5gY6Z/2/ is the answer that works for me. Thanks Carl!

The final working solution is:
<code>
    var obj = {
      myScale: function(n) {
        return d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain([0, 2])
            .rangePoints([0, 1024])
            .call(null, n);
      }
    }

    console.log(obj.myScale(0)); // returns 0
    console.log(obj.myScale(2)); // returns 1024
</code>

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that the function returned by d3 is maintaining some sort of state when calling it. However, you are recreating it each time you call it when assigned to your `obj`

Because no state is maintained it can't calculate the appropriate results.

If you are trying to call directly to the instance of your function, this might be a better approach:

```
var obj = {
   returnResult: d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain([0, 2])
      .rangePoints([0, 1024])
}
```

This would allow you to do what you are doing now without recreating the object each time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. @cesutherland came up with a solution that fit my needs here: http://jsfiddle.net/cesutherland/5gY6Z/2/